# Why can't Perl find the library in my t/ directory?

Tags: perl

I have a .pm file in my current directory /t, and I inserted this line of code:

```
use lib qw(.);
```

Then I inserted this line of code

```
use TestUtil.pm;
```

where TestUtil.pm is in the current directory, but I keep getting this error:

> Can't locate TestUtil.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . ........ ( Note that @INC contains the current directory)

#### `TestUtil.pm`:

```
package TestUtil;

use strict; use warnings;

BEGIN { use Exporter (); use vars qw( $VERSION @ISA @EXPORT );

# Set the version for version checking
$VERSION = 1.00; @ISA = qw( Exporter ); @EXPORT = qw(_a ); }

use vars qw( $VERSION @ISA @EXPORT );

sub _a { return 1; }
```

#### `test_XXX.t`:

```
use lib qw(.); use strict; use warnings;

use TestUtil;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the headers (say, first 10 lines or so) of both Perl files?  It will be a little easier to help troubleshoot if we can see it :)

Comment: Please edit the original posting to contain all relevant code (without errors), and delete your reply below. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your test like so:

prove --lib t

Then your working directory is actually a level above t/

So in your package (source file`t/TestUtil.pm`)

```
package t::TestUtil;
use strict; use warnings;
```

And in your test_XXX.t

```
use lib '.';
use t::TestUtil;
```

I've seen it done this way in several CPAN modules.

Comment: That's a good point: it would be helpful to know how the script is being invoked, and where the modules are located.

Comment: This worked! The fact that my working directory was a level above t/. Thanks snoopy, bedwyr and cberg!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the .pm from the module name in the "use ..." statement.

Comment: Oh sorry I originally did not have the .pm in it.
Also I tried require "./TestUtil.pm"; which did not work (and yes, this one has a .pm in it)

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the TestUtil.pm as a TestUtil module?

```
# in your TestUtil module...
package TestUtil;
```

EDIT:

Is your Perl module (TestUtil.pm) returning a status?  Try adding this to the end of the TestUtil.pm file:

```
1;
```

Comment: So I have:

# in my TestUtil.pm file...
package TestUtil;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub a{

}

# in my test_XXX.t file...
use lib qw(.);
use TestUtil;

Comment: Can you paste the code in your original question? It's hard to think of potential solutions w/out more information.

Answer (score 0):

In TestUtil.pm

---

> package TestUtil;
>
> use strict; use warnings;
>
> BEGIN {   use Exporter   ();   use
>   vars       qw( $VERSION @ISA @EXPORT
>   );
>
> # Set the version for version
>   checking
>   $VERSION     = 1.00;   @ISA         =
>   qw( Exporter );   @EXPORT      = qw(_a
>                      ); }
>
> use vars qw( $VERSION @ISA @EXPORT );
>
> sub _a {   return 1; }

---

In test_XXX.t

---

use lib qw(.);
use strict;
use warnings;

use TestUtil;

---

Comment: Just an etiquette-thing: it's best to post any updates to your question in the original source of the question. This way your responses don't get lost when other potential solutions are up-voted.

Comment: Sorry. The character limit did not allow me to make it as a comment.

Comment: See my original post -- one more quick idea.  This worked for me when I copied your code.

Comment: @Kys, it's best to edit your original question. I like to use "EDIT" statements to show where my answer has been revised.